# Fetch previous value on a field using chatter feed history

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking

We want to retrieve the previous value for the owner field on all the Opportunity records in our org. Is there a way to do this via the chatter history? Feed tracking was not enabled for the 'Owner' field, unfortunately.

EDIT* :  We actually want to revert back the previous owners on all the Opportunities in our org, since a batch job incorrectly updated all the owners and we don't have any data backup.

Comment: You want to track if the Owner changes in an opportunity? Why do you want to use Chatter? to inform that there is a change on the Opportunity's owner?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Updated the description, we actually just want to revert back the previous owners on all the Opps in our org.

Comment: Well, I understand what you want, I think :) ... So you want to update your Opportunities Owner's with the old values. This will be one step back. For that you don't need to use Chatter Feed. oldMap will contain the old values for the Owner.  To be honest, this operation can be a bit tricky. Is this one time only operation?